# Submitting R package that use OpenMP

Tags: c++, r, openmp

I tried to submit R package which support OpenMP  (This package can be compiled in Linux if openmp  is available).

I have got this error when I checked may package.

> checking compilation flags in Makevars ... WARNING
>   Non-portable flags in variable ‘PKG_CXXFLAGS’:
>     -fopenmp

How can I suppress this error and submit it to the CRAN.

Comment: It's not an error. It's a warning.

Comment: That means I can submit it to the CRAN without any problem?

Comment: You should probably look at other packages that have external dependencies.

Comment: Which packages in the CRAN use OpenMP?

Comment: Well, for one I would guess that http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OpenMPController/index.html does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [R Extensions Manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#OpenMP-support), you need:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
```

See [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Rcpp-with-OpenMP-Need-example-Makevars-td4667882.html) for a recent R-help post with example CRAN packages and more information.